# Understanding genetic algorithms and other machine learning, where to begin?

Tags: behavior, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

To start I should provide a brief summary as to why I am asking this. Currently I am a  university student beginning the last assignment of an honors degree in Digital Media Design. I have become wildly interested in Artificial Intelligence as of late, and am looking to include some nifty things in the said assignment.

The main topic I wish to cover is emergent behaviors, which would be visually communicated back to user as they interact with this project. Anyway, I have been reading a great text by Stephen Marsland called Machine Learning. I can't really pretend to know a lot about the topics yet, but I feel as if it is a guide to an intermediate level of many Machine Learning topics and techniques.

[Machine Learning by Stephen Marsland](http://books.google.co.nz/books?hl=en&lr=&id=n66O8a4SWGEC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=machine+learning+stephen+marsland&ots=vUXrTT8KWm&sig=42CHCdpi2KQNAyJXsjntUHA1QPs#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I have been going through the book strategically cover to cover and am about half way. I have learnt about Neural Networks like the multi-layer perceptions and radial basis networks, being used to solve linear, classification and time-series problems/situations. I then struggled through some ideas about support vector machines and, slowly, I am getting my head around high-dimensionality and kernel-tricks.

However, things get sad now, I am beginning to drag myself through some of the content and I am really struggling to hold a conscious understanding of the techniques and mathematics being presented. Further more, as I try to program the examples I am taking longer and longer to piece together the blanks (so to speak). Now, I am not looking for a simple, hard and fast way out, but I am also conscious of the time I have left to pull this project together.

If anyone else has had a similar experience, which they are now on the other side of, could they perhaps share an opinion on a couple of things with me. Would you suggest jumping right into the genetic algorithms and working back over the other topics as I gain more experience, or would this be unmanageable? Or perhaps another topic that works nicely leading into genetic algorithms? I have a reasonable grasp of mathematics and programming concepts, but am completely self taught (my degree focuses on design rather than computer sciences and software engineering).

And perhaps if so, is there any resources you might be able to share with me, or snippets of advice? I will be hugely grateful, and thank you to everyone in advance.

**TL;DR** Need a push in the right direction with genetic algorithms for an emergent behavior project. Please share any good resources.

(Apologies for long question, first time asker).

Comment: NP, great question.. even though it's totally off topic ;). Even though I was bottom of the totem, I worked for a Machine Learning company that was lucky enough to be acquired by Google. So, I totally understand your fascination with the topic. Anyways check out the resources in my answer, they'll probably guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you Toby Segaran's book: *Programming Collective Intelligence*.
Actually, it doesn't contains much academical knowledge (with a huge scary equations and tons of math) but real word primers that could help you to intuitively feel ML algorithms.

Comment: Oh great I will see if I can spot it in the library in town. Thanks for that.

Is it common to feel pretty lost coming into these kind of topics? I kind of feel like I am getting the hang of it, but also might be learning from incorrect assumptions i'm making.

Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: (Sorry, I forgot to accept the answer for this, just done it now :P )

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this

http://www.ml-class.org/

.. from the website

> A bold experiment in distributed education, "Machine Learning" will be
>   offered free and online to students worldwide during the fall of 2011.
>   Students will have access to lecture videos, lecture notes, receive
>   regular feedback on progress, and receive answers to questions. When
>   you successfully complete the class, you will also receive a statement
>   of accomplishment. Taught by Professor Andrew Ng, the curriculum draws
>   from Stanford's popular Machine Learning course. A syllabus and more
>   information is available [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/). Sign up below to receive additional
>   information about participating in the online version when it becomes
>   available.

and perhaps even a better resource could one day be StackExchanges own Machine Learning Q/A site which you can [follow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning) to get off the ground.

or some of these existing sattellite machine learning Q/A sites

http://CrossValidated.com (on Stack)

http://metaoptimize.com/qa/

Comment: Hey that ML class looks really great! I am currently tied up with another degree, but i'll check it out once i'm done.

Anyway, thanks a bunch for putting those links forwards, I don't know why I hadn't managed to stumble upon them before... think I might go hand out on CrossValidated for a bit. 

Thanks again dude.

Answer (score 1):

Its specific to genetic programming but i think still pretty useful, because the differences are not so big.
Its even free available: http://www.gp-field-guide.org.uk/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else was interested in this kind of thing I have found some interesting resources online.

Firstly, an artificial life forum called [FreshSim](http://www.freshsim.org/) that has a good user base and friendly people. The forum has all kinds of algorithms for a-life being discussed.

Also I found a framework for agent-based models, which tend to be large scale a-life programs, called [Swarm](http://www.swarm.org/index.php/Swarm_main_page#Getting_started_if_you_are_new_to_Swarm).